# How to create two date picker using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to create a date picker like the following image [Range Date Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXcxb.png) using flutter. How did I achieve this functionality without using syncfusion package as it is  licensed package

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker 's `Multi-date picker view` package or you can also create a in which you can use two `DatePickerDialog` widget in a row and handle both the datepickers on your own